# How to reference the `this` attribute of a class method when passed to a function as a callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, methods

I have a class with a method that accesses some instance properties of the class. I am trying to call this method by passing it as a callback to an outside function, but my approach causes the program to crash at runtime because the `this` attribute is `undefined`. From what I read, this could be because the function is defining its own `this`, which is why I made it an arrow function, but that still doesn't resolve the issue. Here is an approximation of the code:

```js
class Foo {
  bar = 0;

  modifyBar(value) {
    this.bar = value; // TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bar')
  }

  constructor() {
    call(this.modifyBar);
  }
}

const call = (callback) => {
  // ...
  callback(1);
};

const foo = new Foo();
```

I have tried using the `method.call` attribute and passing in the class `this` attribute, but to me that seems like a hack and unnecessarily verbose. **My question is: what's the reason that `this` evaluates to `undefined` at runtime?**

This is the code that achieves what I want using `method.call`:

```js
class Foo {
  bar = 0;

  modifyBar(value) {
    this.bar = value;
  }

  constructor() {
    call(this, this.modifyBar);
  }
}

const call = (instance, callback) => {
  // ...
  callback.call(instance, 1);
};

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar); // 1
```

P.S. I know that the way my logic is setup seems abstract, and that I could simply move `call` into the class definition, but in my actual application it is more of a utility function that performs various side effects in different contexts. This is why I'm looking for a solution to do it exactly this way.

Comment: This is quite a common problem; just use `this.modifyBar.bind(this)`.